# How can I use a global dashboard filter in a SAQL Query?

Tags: saql, tableau-crm

If I have a global filter on a dashboard (e.g. `Account_Name`), is it possible to reference that filter in a SAQL query something like:

```
q = load "My_data_recipe";
q = filter q by 'Account_name' == "Dashboard_filter.Account_Name";
```

Many thanks in advance!